# NGINX returning HTTP 502, but HTTP 200 in the logs

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have trouble investigating an HTTP 502 response returned by an NGINX instance.

When this happens in the browser:

[image]

This is what I see in the logs:

```
10.244.1.82 - - [14/Apr/2022:09:21:26 +0000] "GET /add HTTP/1.1" 200 3811
"https://myapplication.com/bar" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.79 Safari/537.36"
```

**Where else to look for the reason of HTTP 502 NGINX response?**

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy. It forwards traffic to a PHP Zend application. Before I got here, I was getting HTTP 502 and the logs were mentioning *upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream*, so I increased buffer sizes. Now the logs are saying HTTP 200, but the result in the browser hasn't changed.

Comment: This is weird! Did you try clearing the browser cache? or else try sending requests using the curl command.

Comment: What's your `nginx` config contents? What is in `error.log`? Is there anything in Zend framework logs?

Comment: After enabling the error log I can see entries saying: "2022/04/15 14:48:40 [info] 34#34: *2257 client (...) closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out I forgot I have another NGINX between the client and the NGINX instance that I was checking the logs of.

I am using [Kubernetes Ingress NGINX Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). I needed to add the following two annotations to my Ingress configuration ([documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#proxy-buffers-number)):

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers-number: "8"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
```